# Morphism of sketches inducing a (co)reflective subcategory

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra

Certain morphisms of theories gives rise to (co)reflective subcategories of their models. For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to fix my definition of sketch to be a category $\mathbb{C}$ with a chosen class of limits $L$, $(\mathbb{C},L)$. If $L' \subseteq L$, then we certainly have that $Mod(\mathbb{C},L')$ is a reflective subcategory of $Mod(\mathbb{C},L)$. For a *coreflective* category, we can take the inclusion of vector bundles into the category of double vector bundles, where $A \xrightarrow{q} M$ becomes the double vector bundle $ M \xleftarrow{q} A \xrightarrow{q} M $ (the base is just identity $M = M$) and the core construction gives the coreflector (see more details on the core [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50275605_On_Double_Vector_Bundles)).

I can't seem to find any reference on essentially algebraic theories or limit sketches that gives any clear conditions for *when* a morphism of sketches induces a (co)reflective morphism of theories.